# Populate a array of objects in mongo with node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, object

I have this model

```
var clienteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nome:            String,
    profissao:       String,
    estado_civil:    String,
    data_nascimento: String,
    cpf:             String,
    cidade:          String,
    endereco:        String,
    data_cadastro:   {
        type:    Date,
        default: Date.now
        },
    telefone:        String,
    estadias:        [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Estadia"
    }]
});
```

I am trying this to populate but to no avail.

```
Cliente.findById({ _id: req.params.id }).populate("estadias.Estadia").exec((err,cliente)=>{
```

How I can do this?

Comment: I think you just want `populate("estadias")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the function .populate ("estadias") but first make sure you have data in your database, in this case, I was trying but another error in the creation of the documents made it empty